# prevent ipad screenlock/screensaver/sleep

Tags: ipad, sleep, ios7.1, screen-lock

I'm trying to run automated testing of an iPad running 7.1.2.  This machine is in a lab and always plugged in.  For testing reasons, we need to prevent the screensaver (screenlock, sleep mode) from ever coming on.  I've tried the obvious of setting "Settings > General > Auto-lock > Never", however it still locks.  I've also tried resetting (by holding down sleep and home buttons at the same time for about 10 seconds until it reboots).

When I come back to the iPad hours later, the screen is blank.  I have to hit the home button and then "slide to unlock" (no password). The fact that the iPad is locked is causing tests to fail.  The other iPad we have (running 6.1.3) doesn't have this issue.  And I understand before this one was upgraded to 7.1.2, it also didn't have this problem.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are testing the software (app) that is being built then use the following in app delegate and it prevents it from going to sleep mode:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

as far as the iPad itself you have already done what it needs to be done in general and settings. i recommend trying to reset the iPad and see if auto lock never works.